# Transpose rows to columns and columns to row

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I have the following code which I use to transpose rows to columns

```
awk '/VE464 V4.1.06/{if(s){print s;s=$0}else{s=$0}}
        /Normal Acq/{s=s";"$0}
        /SL/{s=s";"$0}
    /SN/{s=s";"$0}          
    /Gps Status/{s=s";"$0}     
    /GPGGA/{s=s";"$0}        
    /GNGSA/{s=s";"$0}         
    /GPZDA/{s=s";"$0}         
    /PTNL/{s=s";"$0}            
    /TB/{s=s";"$0}      
END{print s}' input.txt
```

My input data is this (input.txt):

```
% VE464 V4.1.06
% Normal Acq 
% SL            : 30391.00
% SN            : 48097.00
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,034403.00,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,5,15,0.7,207.283,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6
% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,87,72,65,66,88,81,78,,,,,,1.6,0.7,1.5*27
% GNGST         : $GNGST,034403.00,0.001,0.053,0.046,127.2,0.049,0.050,0.017*44
% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,034403.02,25,11,2017,00,00*67
% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,034403.00,112517,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,12,15,1.6,EHT174.943,M*4C
% TB            : 17/11/25 03:43:51:732000 [13431732000 microsec]

% VE464 V4.1.06
% Normal Acq 
% SL            : 30385.00
% SN            : 48161.00
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035229.00,2059.52294297,N,05034.93435481,E,5,16,0.7,201.012,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6
% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,20,25,18,29,15,10,26,21,,,,,1.5,0.7,1.4*2F
% GNGST         : $GNGST,035229.00,0.002,0.053,0.046,136.0,0.050,0.049,0.017*4A
% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035229.01,25,11,2017,00,00*6B
% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035229.00,112517,2059.52294297,N,05034.93435481,E,12,16,1.5,EHT168.672,M*43
% TB            : 17/11/25 03:52:17:180000 [13937180000 microsec]

% VE464 V4.1.06
% Normal Acq 
% SL            : 30387.00
% SN            : 48161.00
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035313.00,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,5,14,0.7,199.952,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*
% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,20,25,18,29,15,10,26,21,,,,,1.7,0.7,1.6*2F
% GNGST         : $GNGST,035313.00,0.001,0.053,0.046,138.5,0.050,0.049,0.017*4A
% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035313.01,25,11,2017,00,00*63
% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035313.00,112517,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,12,14,1.7,EHT167.612,M*4F
% TB            : 17/11/25 03:53:01:180000 [13981180000 microsec]

% VE464 V4.1.06
% Normal Acq 
% SL            : 30389.00
% SN            : 48161.00
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035348.00,2059.55364804,N,05034.93016495,E,5,15,0.7,199.466,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*
% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,87,79,65,66,88,78,,,,,,,1.6,0.7,1.4*24
% GNGST         : $GNGST,035348.00,0.001,0.053,0.046,138.4,0.050,0.049,0.016*44
% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035348.01,25,11,2017,00,00*6D
% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035348.00,112517,2059.55364804,N,05034.93016495,E,12,15,1.6,EHT167.125,M*46
% TB            : 17/11/25 03:53:36:380000 [14016380000 microsec]
```

Then the output i got whit my code is ( rows transposed to columns separated by ; )

```
% VE464 V4.1.06;% Normal Acq ;% SL            : 30391.00;% SN            : 48097.00;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,034403.00,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,5,15,0.7,207.283,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,034403.00,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,5,15,0.7,207.283,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6;% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,87,72,65,66,88,81,78,,,,,,1.6,0.7,1.5*27;% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,034403.02,25,11,2017,00,00*67;% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,034403.00,112517,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,12,15,1.6,EHT174.943,M*4C;% TB            : 17/11/25 03:43:51:732000 [13431732000 microsec]
% VE464 V4.1.06;% Normal Acq ;% SL            : 30385.00;% SN            : 48161.00;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035229.00,2059.52294297,N,05034.93435481,E,5,16,0.7,201.012,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035229.00,2059.52294297,N,05034.93435481,E,5,16,0.7,201.012,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6;% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,20,25,18,29,15,10,26,21,,,,,1.5,0.7,1.4*2F;% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035229.01,25,11,2017,00,00*6B;% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035229.00,112517,2059.52294297,N,05034.93435481,E,12,16,1.5,EHT168.672,M*43;% TB            : 17/11/25 03:52:17:180000 [13937180000 microsec]
% VE464 V4.1.06;% Normal Acq ;% SL            : 30387.00;% SN            : 48161.00;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035313.00,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,5,14,0.7,199.952,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035313.00,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,5,14,0.7,199.952,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*;% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,20,25,18,29,15,10,26,21,,,,,1.7,0.7,1.6*2F;% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035313.01,25,11,2017,00,00*63;% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035313.00,112517,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,12,14,1.7,EHT167.612,M*4F;% TB            : 17/11/25 03:53:01:180000 [13981180000 microsec]
% VE464 V4.1.06;% Normal Acq ;% SL            : 30389.00;% SN            : 48161.00;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035348.00,2059.55364804,N,05034.93016495,E,5,15,0.7,199.466,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035348.00,2059.55364804,N,05034.93016495,E,5,15,0.7,199.466,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*;% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,87,79,65,66,88,78,,,,,,,1.6,0.7,1.4*24;% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035348.01,25,11,2017,00,00*6D;% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035348.00,112517,2059.55364804,N,05034.93016495,E,12,15,1.6,EHT167.125,M*46;% TB            : 17/11/25 03:53:36:380000 [14016380000 microsec]
```

After I do some process with the previous output i will get (clean output):

```
% VE464 V4.1.06;% Normal Acq ;% SL            : 30391.00;% SN            : 48097.00;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,034403.00,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,5,15,0.7,207.283,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,034403.00,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,5,15,0.7,207.283,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6;% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,87,72,65,66,88,81,78,,,,,,1.6,0.7,1.5*27;% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,034403.02,25,11,2017,00,00*67;% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,034403.00,112517,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,12,15,1.6,EHT174.943,M*4C;% TB            : 17/11/25 03:43:51:732000 [13431732000 microsec]
% VE464 V4.1.06;% Normal Acq ;% SL            : 30387.00;% SN            : 48161.00;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035313.00,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,5,14,0.7,199.952,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*;% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035313.00,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,5,14,0.7,199.952,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*;% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,20,25,18,29,15,10,26,21,,,,,1.7,0.7,1.6*2F;% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035313.01,25,11,2017,00,00*63;% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035313.00,112517,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,12,14,1.7,EHT167.612,M*4F;% TB            : 17/11/25 03:53:01:180000 [13981180000 microsec]
```

Then, using the previous file is will like to transpose from columns to row keeping the same format as original file (input.txt )

Final output should be this one:

```
% VE464 V4.1.06
% Normal Acq 
% SL            : 30391.00
% SN            : 48097.00
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,034403.00,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,5,15,0.7,207.283,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6
% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,87,72,65,66,88,81,78,,,,,,1.6,0.7,1.5*27
% GNGST         : $GNGST,034403.00,0.001,0.053,0.046,127.2,0.049,0.050,0.017*44
% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,034403.02,25,11,2017,00,00*67
% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,034403.00,112517,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,12,15,1.6,EHT174.943,M*4C
% TB            : 17/11/25 03:43:51:732000 [13431732000 microsec]

% VE464 V4.1.06
% Normal Acq 
% SL            : 30387.00
% SN            : 48161.00
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035313.00,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,5,14,0.7,199.952,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*
% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,20,25,18,29,15,10,26,21,,,,,1.7,0.7,1.6*2F
% GNGST         : $GNGST,035313.00,0.001,0.053,0.046,138.5,0.050,0.049,0.017*4A
% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035313.01,25,11,2017,00,00*63
% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035313.00,112517,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,12,14,1.7,EHT167.612,M*4F
% TB            : 17/11/25 03:53:01:180000 [13981180000 microsec]
```

Would you check my code to transpose from row to column if this can be improve and more easy, and using the last (clean output) transpose from columns to row?

Comment: This is a somewhat non-specific description: `After I do some process with the previous output.` I'm pretty sure there is no need to transpose at all, if you explain the criteria for the filtering step. Perhaps it can be accomplished with a `sed` regex. Please elaborate on the filtering step from 4 to 2.

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need much programming!

```
$ tr ';' '\n' <file
```

will do the job, unless I missed some detail?!

```
% VE464 V4.1.06
% Normal Acq
% SL            : 30391.00
% SN            : 48097.00
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,034403.00,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,5,15,0.7,207.283,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,034403.00,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,5,15,0.7,207.283,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*6
% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,87,72,65,66,88,81,78,,,,,,1.6,0.7,1.5*27
% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,034403.02,25,11,2017,00,00*67
% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,034403.00,112517,2059.56495319,N,05034.47277356,E,12,15,1.6,EHT174.943,M*4C
% TB            : 17/11/25 03:43:51:732000 [13431732000 microsec]
% VE464 V4.1.06
% Normal Acq
% SL            : 30387.00
% SN            : 48161.00
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035313.00,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,5,14,0.7,199.952,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*
% Gps Status    : $GPGGA,035313.00,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,5,14,0.7,199.952,M,-32.341,M,1.0,0000*
% GNGSA         : $GNGSA,A,3,20,25,18,29,15,10,26,21,,,,,1.7,0.7,1.6*2F
% GPZDA         : $GPZDA,035313.01,25,11,2017,00,00*63
% PTNL         : $PTNL,GGK,035313.00,112517,2059.54233727,N,05034.93011171,E,12,14,1.7,EHT167.612,M*4F
% TB            : 17/11/25 03:53:01:180000 [13981180000 microsec]
```

to add an empty line between records

```
$ sed '$!G' file | tr ';' '\n'
```

assuming there is an empty line between records, to convert to columns can be simplified to

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS= -v OFS=';' -v ORS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Comment: great, how to improve the code I have to transpose from row to columns separated by ;

Comment: Is there the possibility to do it as array, as I did in my code to be able to select some of the rows and not all. Per example rows 3,4 and 10 for each patch ( I call patch every time a break in VE464 ). My code works but if there is other options. I believe it is there . please can u share.. Thanks